# Enable/disable body scroll on mobile with addEventlistener

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I know this might seem like a duplicate but I have looked at previous answers on the site but with no success when trying to implement the different solutions.

So, here it goes.

I have created a page where I am obliged to have a modal/disclaimer due to sensitive information.
I have managed to disable  background body scroll on both desktop and mobile. On desktop I have also managed to reenable the scroll after the button in the modal has been clicked. On mobile, however, the scroll maintains disabled after the user has clicked the button in the modal.

Here is my JS:

```
<script>
   window.onload = function () {
       $('body').css('overflow','hidden')
       document.body.addEventListener("touchmove", function(event) {
               event.preventDefault();
           }, false);
       document.getElementById('button').onclick = function () {
           $('body').css('overflow','scroll')
           document.body.addEventListener("touchmove", function(event) {
               event.preventDefault();
           }, true);
           document.getElementById('modal').style.display = "none"
       }; 
   };
</script>
```

As you can see, I have tried adding 'true' at the end of the same event listener as the button is clicked. This does not work :(

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the best way is not trying to disable the scrolling. You can set your modal container style position to "fixed" and it won't be affected by the scrolling. Find below an example of a container that fills the screen. I hope it helps.

```
<body>
    <div id="modal-container" style="position:fixed; top:0px; left:0px; width:100%; height:100%"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The thing is - if the user can scroll, they can also see the content in the background and I cannot let them see it, unless they press the button in the modal.
I also want the top part of the page in the background visible. The modal will be located at the bottom of the viewport

Comment: So you can try to put the page body with "overflow: hidden" to avoid the body content scrolling.

Comment: Hi! Thanks again. If you look at the code though, thats exactly what I am doing. I am also doing that for iOS. The issue Im having is regarding how I reenable the scroll on mobile, once the button in the modal is clicked.